# Is it possible to add advertising in Google News App

Tags: ads, smartphone, google-news

I realized Smartphone applications with Google News API. And I want to know if it's possible (I mean legal) to add advertisements on these apps ?

I used the RSS feed (the API is deprecated). In this [link](http://support.google.com/news/bin/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=fr&answer=40796) it says : "We invite you to make noncommercial use of Google's RSS feeds", but I'm not sure to find a good definition to noncommercial. Must it be advertising-free ?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the Google news search API, whose T&C are described here? https://developers.google.com/news-search/terms. If you mean a different one, can you provide a link to the relevant T&C doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-commercial means that you can use it for personal use and not for business. Showing advertisements in your feed would very likely constitute non-personal use. After all: you want to show the ads so that you can make some money. That's a business.

I can also easily imagine that showing the RSS feed on a company web site or on a personal web site that shows advertisements next to the feed, is also interpreted as commercial use.

Of course I am not a lawyer (nor are most people here, given that the programmer's focus of Stack Overflow), but I tend to err on the side of caution in cases like these.

Answer (score 0):

In the google link it's clearly mentioned what is commercial.

Commercial use of feeds (ex. to sell a product or service, to increase traffic to your site).

So i think shows ads is not commercial.